# Wann wird der (oder den) Kuchen für uns bereit sein?

Tags: grammar-identification

My inquiry is whether or not I should use the nominative der or the accusative den in the sentence "Wann wird der (oder den) Kuchen für uns bereit sein?"

Is it accusative since the main verb in the construction "wird bereit sein" = "will be ready" is sein?

What grammatical function then do the words "wird" and "bereit" have in this sentence? Are they auxiliary verbs?

Any insight would be helpful! :)

Comment: What makes you think, the case is determined by the main verb? If you rely on a book/rule, could you please cite it? There seems to be a misunderstanding of some sort...

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was not paying attention when I asked this question but Dirk's answer cleared this up for me. I'm still wondering though, what grammatical function in German the words "wird" and "bereit" serve in this sentence? If "sein" is the main verb then are "wird" and "bereit" auxiliary or helping verbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wann wird der Kuchen für uns bereit sein?

*What grammatical function then do the words "wird" and "bereit" have in this sentence? Are they auxiliary verbs?*

**Bereit** is an adjective, and as you can see from the missing case ending, it's used as an adverb.

**Wird** is third person singular (The subject *der Kuchen* does this) of the auxiliary *werden*, which marks the *Futur I* tense if used with an infinitive (here: *sein*). As an alternative, you may use the *Präsens* tense.

> Wann ist der Kuchen für uns bereit?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to look for the main verb, you have to look for the subject.
The subject in this sentence is "der Kuchen", so it is der, not den.